# Sort Matrix in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm having trouble using `cv::sort` functionality in **C++** API of **OpenCV**.

I'm trying to sort `cv::Mat` contents in **OpenCV** using

`cv::sort(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int flags);`

The following code gives me a compilation error. I'm not sure whats wrong with this code:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat matrix(5,5,CV_32F,Scalar(0)),m;
    randn(matrix, 2.00, 1.00);
    cout<<"before sorting:\n"<<matrix<<endl;
    sort(matrix, m, CV_SORT_EVERY_ROW + CV_SORT_ASCENDING);
    cout<<"after sorting:\n"<<m<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use cv::sort() rather than sort(), even you are using namespace cv. That is because C++ has an implementation of sort() in namespace std and simply using sort() will make a conflict.

Comment: it sometimes feels silly. It again reminded me that I need to be careful while using multiple namespaces. Thank you.